# How to make Apple Sign In Revoke Token POST Request?

Tags: swift, authentication, token, digital-signature

How do I structure a swift POST request to satisfy the Sign In With Apple token revocation requirements?

I am not sure what form-data, client_id, client_secret, token, or token_type_hint are supposed to be. I was able to implement Sign in With Apple to create a user, but very lost on the revocation part of this.

I am looking to perform this client-side with Swift, as that would be the most convenient. Firebase may be developing a solution built into their SDK, but not sure if that is a one-size fits all solution for developers using Firebase.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens#url

Edit: source of requirements https://developer.apple.com/support/offering-account-deletion-in-your-app

The following functions live in the same class (ViewModel). The first does my login/registration flow. Some of the code is related to Firebase flows and can be largely ignored, but you can see I grab the token string and nonce for client_secret. The second function resembles the POST request for token revocation (which gets called from a delete account function not shown). Has anyone had success with this approach/boilerplate?

Testing the token revocation method below with a button tap in my app returns status code 400. I cannot revoke tokens with this method, and I am not sure what else to do.

```
public func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    // Sign in using Firebase Auth
    if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
        guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
            print("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
            return
        }
        
        // JWT
        guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
            print("Unable to fetch identity token")
            return
        }
        
        guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
            print("Unable to serialize token string from data")
            return
        }
        
        let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: idTokenString, rawNonce: nonce)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { result, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            else { // successful auth, we can now check if its a login or a registration
                guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
                    print("No user was found.")
                    return
                }
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(("\(user.uid)"))
                docRef.getDocument{ (document, error) in
                    if let document = document, document.exists {
                        // User is just logging in, their db store exists
                        print("Successful Apple login.")
                        
                        // Token revocation requirements
                        self.clientSecret = nonce
                        self.appleToken = idTokenString
                        
                        if (self.isDeletingAccount == true) {
                            print("Is deleting account.")
                            self.isReauthenticated = true
                        }
                        self.isLogged = true
                    }
                    else { // document does not exist! we are registering a new user
                        db.collection("Users").document("\(user.uid)").setData([
                            "name": "\(appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName ?? "")"
                        ])
                        print("Successful Apple registration.")
                        
                        self.clientSecret = nonce
                        self.appleToken = idTokenString
                        
                        self.isLogged = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// POST request to revoke user's Apple token 
func appleAuthTokenRevoke(completion: (([String: Any]?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    
    let paramString: [String : Any] = [
        "client_id": Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, //"com.MyCompany.Name",
        "client_secret": self.clientSecret,
        "token": self.appleToken,
        "token_type_hint": "access_token"
    ]
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke")!
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramString, options: .prettyPrinted)
    }
    catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion?(nil, error)
    }
    
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, error == nil else {
            print("error", error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))
            return
        }
        
        guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {
            print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            return
        }
        
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        else {
            print("deleted accont")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: What are the "upcoming June 30th requirements"?

Comment: Apps that support Sign in with Apple should use the Sign in with Apple REST API to revoke user tokens

Comment: @Andre were you able to find any solution?

Comment: @ursan526 No, my attempted solution above returns status code 400

Comment: It seems the related firebase job is working on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9906#issuecomment-1159535230

Comment: To Revoke Token - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens

Answer (score 6):

**Note**, I am not familiar with swift, please forgive me that I cannot post a good answer with swift. I found some guys are not clear about the parameters of revoke token API. Hope it will help someone who is not clear about those parameters.

---

The three required values ​​are required for `appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke`.

- client_id: This is the App ID you can find in Apple Developer's Identifiers. Team ID is an excluded identifier.
- **client_secret**: A secret JSON Web Token (JWT) that uses the Sign in with Apple private key associated with your developer account. You need to create it using JWT and download a key file from `developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list`
- **token**: A token that requires revoke. The token is `access_token` or `refresh_token` returned from [`auth/token`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens).

As for the `auth/token`, there are two additional parameters as below

- **code**: The authorization code received in an authorization response sent to your app. The code is single-use only and valid for five minutes. Authorization code validation requests require this parameter. It is the same to the `authorizationCode` key of the response of apple signing, and its type is `base64` (like `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`). It should be decoded to `utf-8` (like `xxxxxxxxxxxx.0.zzzz.YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY`) before assigning to `auth/token` API.
- grant_type: (Required) The grant type determines how the client app interacts with the validation server. Authorization code and refresh token validation requests require this parameter. For authorization code validation, use `authorization_code`. For refresh token validation requests, use `refresh_token`.

Finally, we could call revoke token api (appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke) successfully, and the apple id binding information is deleted under [`Apps Using Apple ID` of `Settings`](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426). And the Node.js sample could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72656409/3011380)

---

Summary the whole process as below.

- Get authorizationCode from Apple login.
- Get a refresh token \ access token with no expiry time using authorizationCode through [`auth\token`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens)
- Revoke the refresh token or access token through [`token\revoke`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens)

Comment: `code: It is the same as the authorization_code key of the response of apple signing, and its type is base64. It should be decoded to utf-8 before assigning to auth/token API.`

*It worked for me without converting to utf-8*

Comment: @YouhanaSheriff, the base64 type of `code` is like `XXXXXXXXXXXX`, whereas, the `utf-8` type of `code` is like `xxxxxxxxxxxx.0.zzzz.YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY` . Which type of `code` is in your case?

Comment: AuthorizationCode leaves only 5 minutes, and can be used only once. Otherwise, I'm getting 400 error. I haven't found this information anywhere except apple official documentation 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens

Comment: @YuraBabiy, Yes, if the Auth code was used over 5 minutes, the 400 error would come up.

Comment: @zangw Thanks. Do you know why apple sends 200 OK on revoke api call, but app is not getting removed under settings?

Comment: @YuraBabiy, you may find some clues from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556424/how-to-validate-the-apple-sign-in-revoke-token-api-successfully-when-handle-dele?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: @YuraBabiy, you may double check the `client_secret` and `token` is correct.

Comment: I found the cause of my issue. I was sending raw response string from refresh token API, instead of just getting the token. Stupid thing, but was hard for me to find )

Answer (score 6):

**For any one who wants to implement account deletion with flutter , swift or react .**

Before you continue reading , take a moment to read the api requirement of two urls you will need to complete the revoking process.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens

The link below shows how to do this with iOS(swift) and firebase using firebase functions .And by reading it you can implement a solution with the other SDKs i.e flutter , react-native etc.

[Implementing account deletion with apple and firebase](https://github.com/jooyoungho/apple-token-revoke-in-firebase)

But in an attempt to  summarise :-

1. When you go through the process of setting up Sign In with Apple you will need to create a key in your apple developer account that comes in a file form  which can be downloaded and should be download on to your device and looks like "*********.p8" where the * stands for a bunch of numbers and words usually representing the key.This apple refers to as the private associated key.

2.This you will use to create a Jwt using popular libraries of your own choosing .which then becomes the **client_secret** parameter for apple's api end point .

3. When you then sign in a user you get an authorisation code(NB:Is the **code** parameter for token generation endpoint)  which you will then make an api call [endpoint](https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token) to generate a token which then become the **token** parameter for the revoke endpoint .

4.Finally you call the [revoke endpoint](https://appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke)  with the parameters from the above processes .

**NB: I believe the solution above is so far the best way assuming that you secure your key on the server side. and unless you have a way of scrambling the key you should not attempt to store this in your project(or app).**

Comment: AuthorizationCode leaves only 5 minutes, and can be used only once. Otherwise, I'm getting 400 error. I haven't found this information anywhere except apple official documentation 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens

Answer (score -1):

The .P8 File is here: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list

For SwiftJWT, it's here: https://github.com/Kitura/Swift-JWT

```
    import SwiftJWT
    func makeJWT() -> String{
        let myHeader = Header(kid: "YOUR KEY ID")
        struct MyClaims: Claims {
            let iss: String
            let iat: Int
            let exp: Int
            let aud: String
            let sub: String
        }
        
        let nowDate = Date()
        var dateComponent = DateComponents()
        dateComponent.month = 6
        let sixDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: nowDate) ?? Date()
        let iat = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
        let exp = Int(sixDate.timeIntervalSince1970)
        let myClaims = MyClaims(iss: "YOUR TEAM ID",
                                iat: iat,
                                exp: exp,
                                aud: "https://appleid.apple.com",
                                sub: "YOUR CLIENT ID")
        
        var myJWT = JWT(header: myHeader, claims: myClaims)
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "CustFiles", withExtension: "bundle") else{
            return ""
        }
        let bundle = Bundle(url: url)
        let path = bundle?.path(forResource: "YOUR AUTHKEY_FILE", ofType: "p8")
        let privateKeyPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path ?? "")
        let privateKey: Data = try! Data(contentsOf: privateKeyPath, options: .alwaysMapped)
        let jwtSigner = JWTSigner.es256(privateKey: privateKey)
        let signedJWT = try! myJWT.sign(using: jwtSigner)
        return signedJWT
    }
```

Add removeAppleAccount Function

```
      func removeAppleAccount() async throws{
        guard let refreshToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.LoginInfo.refreshToken)else{
            return
        }
        let param = "token=\(refreshToken)&client_id=YOUR CLIENT ID&client_secret=\(makeJWT())&token_type_hint=refresh_token".data(using: .utf8)!
        var request : URLRequest! = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke")!)
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = param
        let (_ , response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw FetchAppleTokenError.invalidServerResponse
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.LoginInfo.refreshToken)
        
    }
```

Add getRefreshToken Function in ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate -> authorizationController

```
    import SwiftyJSON
    func getRefreshToken(authorizationCode: Data) async throws{
        guard let codeString = String(data: authorizationCode, encoding: .utf8) else{
            return
        }
        let param = "code=\(codeString)&client_id=YOUR CLIENT ID&client_secret=\(makeJWT())&grant_type=authorization_code".data(using: .utf8)!
        var request : URLRequest! = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token")!)
        request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = param
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw FetchAppleTokenError.invalidServerResponse
        }
        let json: JSON = try! JSON(data: data)
        let refreshToken = json["refresh_token"].string ?? ""
        UserDefaults.standard.set(refreshToken, forKey: UserDefaultKeys.LoginInfo.refreshToken)
    }
    enum FetchAppleTokenError: Error, LocalizedError {
            case invalidServerResponse
    }
```