# How to validate the apple sign in revoke token api successfully when handle delete account on iOS?

Tags: ios, authentication, sign-in-with-apple, delete-account

Per [Account deletion requirement iOS](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12m75xbj)

> If your app offers Sign in with Apple, you’ll need to use the Sign in with Apple REST API to revoke user tokens when deleting an account.

Referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498906/3011380), we are trying to send this revoke token API on our server-side. Here are some snippet

```js
        privateKey = fs.readFileSync("xxxxxxxx.p8")
        client_secret = jwt.sign({ 
                iss: 'xxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx',
                iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 1200,
                aud: 'https://appleid.apple.com',
                sub: "sample.com"
            }, 
            privateKey, 
            { 
                algorithm: 'ES256',
                header: {
                    alg: 'ES256',
                    kid: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
                } 
            });

        data = {
            'token': token,
            'client_id': "sample.com",
            'client_secret': client_secret
        };
        body = qs.stringify(data)

        opts =
            protocol: 'https:'
            host: 'appleid.apple.com'
            path: '/auth/revoke'
            method: 'POST'
            timeout: 6000
            headers:
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)
       // call https to send this opts message
```

And the status code of the above codes could be 200 and the response body is empty.

However, the response code 200 of [revoke token api](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens)

> The request was successful; the provided token has been revoked successfully or was previously invalid.

It seems the status code 200 includes the provided token was previously invalid. How could we distinguish whether the revoke token API was returned by the invalid token or revoked successfully?

We also try to test this revoke token API through `curl` with invalid `client_secret` and `token`, the status code 200 could be returned either and the response body is empty. It is so weird.

```
curl -v POST "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke" \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'client_id=xxx.xxxx.yyyy' \
-d 'client_secret=ddddddeyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IlBGUVRYTTVWUlcifQ.dddd.DmMifw6qWHMqKgDIbO8KrIzDvbF7T4WxxEo9TmtN0kmTISsi8D8FG52k_LPGkbNEnS_-w_SRimEKIH1rsuawFA' \
-d 'token=dddddd' \
-d 'token_type_hint=access_token'

> POST /auth/revoke HTTP/1.1
> Host: appleid.apple.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
> content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 240
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Server: Apple
< Date: Thu, 09 Jun 2022 07:36:31 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Host: appleid.apple.com
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally, we could call revoke token api (appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke) successfully, and the apple id binding information is deleted under [`Apps Using Apple ID` of `Settings`](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426)

---

The root cause is that an invalid token has been used before. We try the identity token of the apple signing result, it is not the correct token.

The correct token is `access_token` or `refresh_token` returned from [`auth/token`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens).

> code - The authorization code received in an authorization response sent to your app. The code is single-use only and valid for five minutes. Authorization code validation requests require this parameter.

In order to get `access_token` or `refresh_token` through `auth/token`, the `code` parameter of `auth/token` request should be paid attention. The `code` authorization response of apple signing, and its type is `base64`. It should be decoded to `utf-8` before assigning to `auth/token` API.

---

Summary the whole process as below.

- Get authorizationCode from Apple login.
- Get a refresh token \ access token with no expiry time using authorizationCode through [`auth\token`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens)
- Revoke the refresh token or access token through [`token\revoke`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens)

Hope the above could help someone who meet the same issue. Here are node.js code snippets.

```js
    getClientSecret: () ->
        client_secret = jwt.sign({ 
                            iss: 'xxxxxxxxx',
                            iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                            exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 360000,
                            aud: 'https://appleid.apple.com',
                            sub: bundleID
                        }, 
                        @privateKey, 
                        { 
                            algorithm: 'ES256',
                            header: {
                                alg: 'ES256',
                                kid: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
                            } 
                        });
        client_secret

    decodeBase64: (base64Data) ->
        buff = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64')
        return buff.toString('utf-8')

    revokeToken: (token) ->
        client_secret = @getClientSecret()

        data = {
            'token': token,
            'client_id': bundleID,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'token_type_hint': 'access_token'
        };

        body = qs.stringify(data)

        opts =
            protocol: 'https:'
            host: 'appleid.apple.com'
            path: '/auth/revoke'
            method: 'POST'
            timeout: 6000
            headers:
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)

        http.post(body, opts)

    authToken: (authCode) ->
        client_secret = @getClientSecret()
        code = @decodeBase64(authCode)

        data = {
            'code': code,
            'client_id': bundleID,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
        };

        body = qs.stringify(data)

        opts =
            protocol: 'https:'
            host: 'appleid.apple.com'
            path: '/auth/token'
            method: 'POST'
            timeout: 6000
            headers:
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)

        http.post(body, opts)
```

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to get `access_token` and `refresh_token` when using Firebase Authentication?

Comment: @algrid, It seems this feature is working on Firebase per https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9906#issuecomment-1159535230

Comment: yes, I saw that, not sure how long it will take for them to implement it though. I want to implement it myself for now, but I can't find a way to get those tokens.

Comment: About how to get this token, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/72656672/3011380, hope it could help you @algrid